# Versioning gulp-generated css/js files in MVC app

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, gulp

I have previously relied on .NET to optimize (concatenate, minify, version) css and js files in my MVC apps.  I recently added grunt to my solution which I've wired in to build events to concatenate, minify, etc. these files and my app will use these grunt-generated files.

The remaining concern I just realized, however, is versioning.  When .NET optimizes a file, they also implement versioning.  It looks like I can just include the gulp-generated files in bundles to handle the versioning, but is there a different way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm handling it in my deployment script. When a deployment is triggered, the deployment script gets the commit sha (deploying via git) and injects it into a web.config setting.

Then inside my Layout file I will reference the css/js files with `/css/app.min.css?version=AppSettings["version"]`

Comment: Sounds like a valid solid.  Unfortunately, the app in question is using TFS.

Comment: Doesn't TFS have something like? Otherwise you could bump the version on your application on deployment and use that instead.